# Socket.io and Node.js with Express >4.0 Version

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have read a few other posts about that issue but didn't seem to get it right.

The socket.io "get started" walkthrough is outdated and tells to do stuff in the app.js file. Since Express 4. everything is handles in the www file.

So far so good - shouldn't be a big deal.

I installed socket.io in the correct project folder with the following command : `npm install --save socket.io`

Right after that I went to the bin/www file and added the following code:

```
...
/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
* Socket IO
*/
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
...
```

Now that I have required socket.io in the www file I shall add the following code to the app.js. Since the the app.js no longer handles the stuff I assume that has to go into the www file as well :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Sadly I have no idea how I can access the variable io outside of the www folder.

I have created a /backend route which should display all online users dynamically. How can I access io on that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your below code from www file into some separate socketjs file.

Where the code into your socketjs file will be like this:-

```
module.exports = function (io) {
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //..

  }
}
```

In this way you can import that socketjs file in your www file like below:-

```
    var app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    socket = require('./socket');

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    socket(io)
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you need to access the variable `io` in router, you can use the `app.set`:

**bin/www:**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.set('io',io);
```

**routes/backend.js:**

```
router.get('/', function(req,res,next) {
  console.log( req.app.get('io') );
});
```